# get Data from Message Queue

Tags: azure, email, message-queue, azure-logic-apps

I have A Logic-App in MS Azure.

First step is to Recieve a Message from a Queue.
Next step should be to send some Parameters from this message to different mail-receiver.

With this code:

```
"@{base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])}@{triggerBody()?['ContentType']}"
```

I get the following message in my mail body:

```
@ string 3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/��{"x_right":220,"x_left":91,"y_right":"OCCUPIED","y_left":"AVAILABLE","deviceid":"R77229040037","timestamp":"2018-01-31T10:58:21.0400000Z"}
```

But I want something like this in my body:

```
Your <DEVICEID> is and distance is <x_left>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the concat function like this:

```
@concat('Your ', json(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])).deviceid, ' and distance is ', json(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])).x_left)
```

Comment: tried your solution. but get this error Message:

InvalidTemplate. Template language expressions in the entries of the action "E-Mail_senden" in line "1" and column "2643" cannot be processed: The template language expression "concat (' Your', base64ToString (triggerBody ()?[' ContentData'].deviceid,' and distance is', base64ToString (triggerBody ()?[' ContentData'].x_left" cannot be evaluated because the "deviceid" property cannot be selected. A property selection is not supported for values of type "String".

Comment: forgot to convert the ContentData to json before trying to access properties. I updated the answer to reflect this.